# Collection framework for collecting performance metrics

Tags: python, perl, frameworks, open-source

I am working on collecting system metrics, running custom scripts to get the application related performance data and storing the data in time-series database(kairosdb with cassandra). I know there is collectd and telegraf framework for the same purpose. collectd seems to satisfy my requirements but not sure about the performance and also we need to run the custom scripts at different interval using exec plugin. I am not sure whether we can achieve this using collectd.

Also i came across telegraf. It is written in go language. It is tag based, so it is easy for me to store the data using kairosdb. But I am not sure how efficient it is and whether it will server my purpose.

Is there any other opensource collection framework available in perl or python to collect system metrics,run custom scripts and store the data in time-series database(kairosdb)?

Answer (score 1):

Just use [Kairosdb REST API](https://kairosdb.github.io/docs/build/html/restapi/index.html) and some HTTP client e.g. [HTTP::Tiny](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTTP::Tiny).

Here an TFTP based example [Kairosdb Stress Yaml](http://codegists.com/code/kairosdb%20stress%20yaml/)